# When designing a website/webapp for iphone, how do you prevent tapping on an input from pushing your page up?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, sencha-touch

When designing a website/webapp for iphone, how do you prevent tapping on an input from pushing your page up?

I have a sencha touch page with a fixed layout and a 'toolbar' up the top, i don't want this from scrolling off the top of the screen when they tap in the input box.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890361/disable-scrolling-in-an-iphone-web-application

Comment: I think that's a separate issue, as sencha already disables scrolling for me.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. When tapping on an input field, some of my content is pushed up to make room for the iphone keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/iscroll-js/issues/detail?id=24) is a workaround, I don't know if there's any other way of accomplishing what you want.

I don't know what you're building, but this might be of use too:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

The above code will prevent the page from beind zoomable.

Credits go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795171/how-do-you-prevent-page-scroll-in-textarea-on-mobile-safari) SO answer.